# How can this be dereferencing ‘void *’ when the pointer was declared with a type?

Tags: c, pointers, scope, c99

I'm trying to make an array with file-level or global scope whose size is determined at runtime. Various articles like [this one](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51010-dynamic-arrays-using-malloc-and-realloc/) suggest this pattern for such a dynamic array:

```
static MISCTYPE *handles;
static int nthreads;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // nthreads set from from argv
    handles = malloc(nthreads * sizeof(MISCTYPE));
    for(i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        handles[i] = miscfunction();
    ...
    free(handles);
    return 0;
}

int otherfunction(...) {
    for(i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        handles[i] = miscfunction();
    ...
}
```

However, everywhere I use the pointer like an array (i.e. `handles[i]`) the compiler says `warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer` and then `error: invalid use of void expression`.

But it's not a void pointer! It definitely has a type (MISCTYPE in this pseudocode), and re-casting it into the same type doesn't stop the errors. Nowhere do I pass it as a `void *` or anything like that.

What's going on here? More importantly, what can I do about it?

Comment: Well, apparently `MISCTYPE` is just another name for `void`. How and where is `MISCTYPE` defined?

Comment: @Olaf: Difference from C++? I'm not aware of any differences between C and C++ when it comes to general status of typedef names. In both C and C++ a typedef name is just an alias for an existing type, not a new type.

Comment: Ah-ha! That's what I get for not digging into the header file! Sure enough, it's defined as `typedef void MISCTYPE`. Now to figure out how that works...

Comment: @AnT: Ok, I take g++ for conforming. As I do not get an error for a test, I assume you are right. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: Okay, found my solution: since the MISCTYPE was indeed void, I can make the global an array of void pointers with `static MISCTYPE **handles;` and allocate it as such with `handles = malloc(nthreads * sizeof(MISCTYPE *));` and the compiler likes it and the code works. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to start with, if the compiler tells you `handles` is a `void *`, you should believe it.  Now, it turns out that `malloc` returns a `void *`, from which we deduce that `handles` is still a `void *` after assignment.

From this we may deduce that the assignment isn't doing what you think it is. At this point we have to ask "so what is `MISCTYPE`", and we, using the code you've posted, can't deduce that.  But if you grok what the `MISCTYPE` is, I bet you'll find the answer.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: This is C. In C `void *` is freely and implicitly convertible to any data pointer type. The fact that `malloc` returns `void *` does allows us to deduce anything about `handles`.

Comment: @Olaf: I presume that was a typo; I fixed it.

Comment: @AnT "... from which we deduce the assignment isn't doing what you think." Whatever MISCTYPE is, the result of the assignment is still a `void*`.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: The target of the assignment is indeed `void *` as we can deduce *from the compiler's error mesage* (which you correctly noted in the first sentence of your answer). But the return type of `malloc` has nothing to do with this deduction and does not contribute to it in any way. That's all I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there must be something goofy with MISCTYPE because the example below works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int *handles;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int i = 0;
    handles = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        handles[i] = i;
    }

    free(handles);
    return 0;
}
```